# divs not displaying with js disabled

Tags: javascript, html

My website all seems to work fine when I have javascript enabled but as soon as I disable it, the main page background renders fine but the actual content doesn't display at all. I thought I had designed it in a gracefully degrading manner. Can anyone shed some light on why the content does not display with JS disabled?

[Website link](http://sonogenics.co.uk/cust/alventura/)

Comment: without looking It uses JavaScript to display the content. :) Either document.write or innerHTML or appendChild.

Comment: Try to post a concise example of your problem were possible please

Comment: Website is blocked by my employer as Proxy Avoidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS on `#main_content` (and other elements) have `display:none;` set which hides the content by default.

You then use javascript to display it. Without javascript, it stays hidden.

Comment: For christ's sake. I can't believe I missed that! I set that initial state so that the ajax load doesn't cause it to flash when JS is enabled. I guess I could just put that CSS into a `noscript`?